# use case diagram for data collection

Tags: software, use-case, engineering

I am creating a project related to education system in which data of universities ,admission and scholarships will be gathered and displayed on site.

In this project I am scraping data from different sites, storing it into database and making it view on site. Actually you can say (correct me if I am wrong) the system is collecting data and makes it viewable.

My questions are:

- Is data collection a use case?
- If it is who will be the actor?

Comment: Note that _actors_ don't necessarily need to be humans. Another system outside your systems boundaries or a bot, can also be considered as an actor. But without additional information, it's hard to answer your question concisely.

Comment: in this project i am scraping data from different sites and storing it into database and making it view on site. actually you can say (correct me if i am wrong) system is collecting data and making it view able

Comment: now please can you answer that in this scenario is data collection can be considered as a use case??

Comment: Use cases can exist without direct interaction of an actor, yes. But you should clearly define your (sub-)system boundaries, though. Other systems (you're) _"scraping"_ that informations from, also can be considered as actors (though the name suggests it, an actor can be passive as well). Also put additional information [into your question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/368907/edit), rather than burying it in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comments, your question is very broad (if not *too broad*, to be *off-topic* here). But let me try to give you a grasp:

> will be gathered and displayed on site ...
>
> is data collection a use case , if it is who will be the actor?

Yes, *data collection* is a **use case** that is a precondition to your primary identified use case of viewing the data (*"displayed on site"*).

The point of use case diagrams is mainly to identify what happens inside / outside of your well defined *system boundaries*. Definition of the system boundary is essential, so a first approach for a diagram might look as follows:

[image]

*Actors* are elements that exist ***outside*** your system boundaries and either trigger actions provided by your system, or being triggered by your system to do something.
The *Actors* can communicate with your system actively or passively. That can be expressed with directed associations in UML.

*Use Cases* have to reside inside your system boundaries, and will describe (even in pure textual form), how the interaction with the *Actors* should be done in more detail.

As shown in the above diagram, actors may be more specialized by means of how they interact with your system (database).

A system boundary and description is dependent on identified ***requirements*** in first place (this might be also part of contracts with 3rd parties, and worth being payed or not!).

Actors can be generalized (specialized) as shown above.

---

If you have identified your systems primary use cases, you may want to break these down, to identify more specific sub-systems (and *extended use cases*), and interaction with your specific *Actors*, e.g. like:

[image]

---

As the ole' saying goes:
*"A picture can be worth to tell more than thousand words, though picture **interpretation** might need whole libraries to be written!"*

Anyways, UML is a generic (picture) language, and comes along with specifically agreed interpretations (only a single book, instead of a *whole library*).

Answer (score 1):

You use 2 action words when describing this activity within your project: "gathered" and also "collected".  Questions to ask are:

- Is this the same activity?  *I think Yes*
- Is this activity necessary to accomplishing the "display" goal?  *I think Maybe*
- What are all the ways this can be accomplished? *Maybe more than one*
- Can these different ways be implemented differently?

My point is that not only is "Data Collection" a use-case, but there are other use-cases involved with the "gather or collect" step, each of which may have one or more actors.

- Directly Linking to external educational datasets may be an option
  and a Linking System may be the actor in this case;
- Downloading exported datasets may be an option in which case a "downloader" utility may be the actor;
- If those downloads are available in different formats, then a format-specific download utility may be an actor for each format-specific downloader (ie, ZIP, CSV, business-specific format.)
- Manual keyboard data entry may be a (last-resort) use-case for those data not available in any other method; and clerical staff (or external staffing resources) may be the actor in this last case.

The key to identifying Use-Cases and Actors is diverging into all the methods/practices involved in achieving a step, then clarifying what requirements are necessary and how those requirements will be met.

Comment: sir i am collecting data through web scrapers from different websites , in this case..... am i (system) is the actor???

Comment: @muntazirabbas The _web-scrapers_ are actors, as I mentioned in my comment.